# Constructing an abstract class from two other abstract class

Tags: c#, templates, design-patterns

Constructing an abstract class from two other abstract classes. For Example

```
public abstract class PlayerBase
{
    public bool IsPlaying { get; set; }
    public abstract void Play();
}
public abstract class VideoPlayerBase : PlayerBase
{
    public abstract void Rotate();
}
public abstract class AudioPlayerBase : PlayerBase
{
    public abstract void Mute();
}
```

What I Want is to use the two other (VideoPlayerBase,AudioPlayerBase) abstract class to build a new VedioAudioPlayerBase abstract class, without much rework.

```
public abstract class VedioAudioPlayerBase
{


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes, but it *does* support multiple implementation of interfaces.

So what you can do is to extract the appropriate methods into an `IVideoPlayer` and an `IAudioPlayer` interface and then write a class that implements both of those.

Unfortunately that means that you can't inherit any implementation.

However, you could encapsulate the audio and video logic in classes that implement IVideoPlayer and IAudioPlayer and use those as the implementation of the AudioVideoPlayer class:

```
public interface IPlayer
{
    bool IsPlaying
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    void Play();
}

public interface IVideoPlayer: IPlayer
{
    void Rotate();
}

public interface IAudioPlayer: IPlayer
{
    void Mute();
}

public interface IAudioVideoPlayer: IVideoPlayer, IAudioPlayer
{
}

public abstract class PlayerBase: IPlayer
{
    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public abstract void Play();
}

public abstract class VideoPlayerBase: PlayerBase, IVideoPlayer
{
    public abstract void Rotate();
}

public abstract class AudioPlayerBase: PlayerBase, IAudioPlayer
{
    public abstract void Mute();
}

public class VideoPlayer: VideoPlayerBase
{
    public override void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("VideoPlayerBaseImpl:Play()");
    }

    public override void Rotate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("VideoPlayerBaseImpl:Rotate()");
    }
}

public class AudioPlayer : AudioPlayerBase
{
    public override void Play()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AudioPlayerBaseImpl:Play()");
    }

    public override void Mute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AudioPlayerBaseImpl:Mute()");
    }
}

public class AudioVideoPlayer: IAudioVideoPlayer
{
    public void Rotate()
    {
        _videoPlayer.Rotate();
    }

    public void Mute()
    {
        _audioPlayer.Mute();
    }

    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get
        {
            return _audioPlayer.IsPlaying && _videoPlayer.IsPlaying;
        }

        set
        {
            _audioPlayer.IsPlaying = value;
            _videoPlayer.IsPlaying = value;
        }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        _audioPlayer.Play();
        _videoPlayer.Play();
    }

    private readonly AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    private readonly VideoPlayer _videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need the implementation of those classes.

Comment: @Taufiq You simply cannot use multiple inheritance of classes to provide the implementation. The best approach is encapsulation and a class/interface hierarchy as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not support multiple inheritance of implementations. The standard way in these kind of situations is to use interfaces and composition:

```
public interface IPlayerBase
{
    IsPlaying { get; set; }
    void Play();
}
public interface IVideoPlayerBase : PlayerBase
{
    void Rotate();
}
public interface IAudioPlayerBase : PlayerBase
{
    void Mute();
}


public abstract class AbstractVideoPlayer : IVideoPlayerBase 
{
    public void Rotate() {
       // implementation
    }
}
public abstract class AbstractAudioPlayer : IAudioPlayerBase 
{
    public abstract void Mute() {
       // implementation
    }
}


public abstract class VedioAudioPlayerBase : IVideoPlayerBase, IAudioPlayerBase
{
    IVideoPlayerBase video;
    IAudioPlayerBase audio;

    public void Rotate() {
       video.Rotate();
    }

    public void Mute() {
       audio.Mute();
    }

}
```